# JMeter: How to inject date from today till past 10 days?

Tags: function, date, jmeter, days

There is a scenario where user will inject today's record, then yesterday's, then day before yesterday, likewise past 10 days.

How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [__timeShift() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) which allows you to generate dates in past/future with arbitrary offsets in desired format:

- Today: `${__timeShift(dd-MM-yyyy,,,,)}`
- Yesterday: `${__timeShift(dd-MM-yyyy,,-P1D,,)}`
- The day before yesterday: `${__timeShift(dd-MM-yyyy,,-P2D,,)}`
- etc.

[image]

More information: [Creating Dates in JMeter Using the TimeShift Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function)

Comment: do we have any shortcut to go back till 100 days? this one looks I need to create script 1 by 1.

Comment: You can inline [__counter() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) in the __timeShift() function like `${__timeShift(dd-MM-yyyy,,-P${__counter(,)}D,,)}`, this way you will get a decremented date each time the function is called